# What are the limitations of the product rule(integration by parts) and when to use it?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

So I was solving this question:
$$\int{1+\tan(x)\tan(x+ \alpha)} \ dx$$
In the process of solving, I had to evaluate the integration of  $tan(x)$
Which I did this way: 
$\int{\tan(x)} \ dx=\int{\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}} \ dx=$$ -\int{\frac{1}{\cos(x)}d(\cos(x))}=-\ln|\cos(x)|+C$

I did it this way
$\int {uv} \ dx = u \int{v} \ dx - \int({u'} \int{v} dx) dx $ but something went wrong:
$$Let \int{\tan(x)} \ dx= \int {\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}} \ dx = I(x)$$
$$\implies I(x)=\int{\sin(x) \sec(x)}dx$$
$$ \implies I(x)=\sec(x)\int{\sin(x)}dx-\int{\frac{d(\sec(x))}{dx}
( \int{\sin(x)dx}})dx $$
$$\implies I(x)=\sec(x)(-\cos(x))-\int{\sec(x) \tan(x)(-\cos(x))}dx$$
$$\implies I(x)=-1+I(x)$$

1. **What have I done wrong in the evaluation of the integral? What does it tell about the integral?**
2. **If it is correct, are there any limitations to the product rule(integration by parts)? When and how must it be used?**
3. 

> Antiderivatives are unique upto a constant

It is clear from the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207389/how-to-explain-why-integration-by-parts-apparently-fails-in-the-case-of-int) what my mistake was.
So, I just wanted to know, if a particle had a velocity of $v_1=\tan t $ and another had a velocity of $v_2=\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}$ and both start from rest and from same position(x,y). The constant 'C' is known for $v_1$, then **why will the value of displacement be $1 \ more \ than \ that \ of \ v_2 \ (evaluated \ the \ 2^{nd} way) $** 
Basically why does $s_2=-1+s_1$(where s is displacement and t is time)

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10146/intuition-behind-the-ilate-rule), the comments and the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10149/1092640) kind of dismiss the ILATE thing as simply a tool for faster simpler calculation so there is no fixed sequence of assuming u and v and that cannot be the mistake.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to tidy up the TeX a bit: remember that common math functions render nicely with a backslash. For example `\sin x` renders $\sin x$ which looks nicer than $sin \ x.$

Comment: 1. Your evaluation is correct! Better questions to ask are “what does your evaluation tell you about the integral?” and “is that information useful?”.

Comment: 2. There are limitation to using the product rule. Like how you assumed $u=\sec x$ was differentiable. You may not know, given an arbitrary function, whether this can be assumed or not.
When can IBP be used? A: Whenever you satisfy the conditions to apply IBP you can use it. Though it may not always be the most useful tool in the world.

Comment: Integration by parts should *not* be called "the product rule." It is not an analogue of the product rule for differentiation; it does not tell you how to integrate products in full generality. It's a trick that simplifies integrals sometimes and often does nothing.

Comment: No wrong because antiderivatives are unique .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2207389/1183190

Comment: @Mostafa antiderivative are unique “up to a constant”.